# cakephp: Admin Plugin Conflict

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I have installed cakephp forum plugin and Admin plugin on my site using composer from www.milesj.me. Forum and Admin plugin has been installed successfully.

But the Admin plugin is making conflict with existing site Admin panel. The URL of the existing site is localhost/domain/admin and this is also the same URL for the Admin plugin.

Does anybody know how to resolve this conflict ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your Config/core.php:

```
/**
 * Uncomment the define below to use CakePHP prefix routes.
 *
 * The value of the define determines the names of the routes
 * and their associated controller actions:
 *
 * Set to an array of prefixes you want to use in your application. Use for
 * admin or other prefixed routes.
 *
 *  Routing.prefixes = array('admin', 'manager');
 *
 * Enables:
 *  `admin_index()` and `/admin/controller/index`
 *  `manager_index()` and `/manager/controller/index`
 *
 */
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

Since the Admin plugin is already using URLs with admin, set this to a different value.

Remember that existing 'admin' methods in your controllers will have to be changed too (e.g. from admin_index() to _index()).

Comment: Did you try to change 'admin' to something else, e.g. 'siteadmin' ?

Comment: Yes but it gives error then... I am wondering this is common problem and no one has answer for this, even I have googled it and could not find the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to modify App/plugin/Admin/Config/routes.php like this

```
    /*
    Router::connect('/admin/'. $section . '/:action/*', $menu['url'], array('section' => $section));
    Router::connect('/admin/'. $section, $menu['url'] + array('action' => 'index'), array('section' => $section));
    */
    Router::connect('/dash/'. $section . '/:action/*', $menu['url'], array('section' => $section));
    Router::connect('/dash/'. $section, $menu['url'] + array('action' => 'index'), array('section' => $section));   
}
/*
Router::connect('/admin/:model/:action/*',
    array('plugin' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'crud'),
    array('model' => '[_a-z0-9]+\.[_a-z0-9]+'));
*/
Router::connect('/dash/:model/:action/*',
    array('plugin' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'crud'),
    array('model' => '[_a-z0-9]+\.[_a-z0-9]+'));

/*
Router::connect('/admin/:action/*', array('plugin' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'admin'));
*/
Router::connect('/dash/:action/*', array('plugin' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'admin'));
```

Sorry. It's a blind shot. Not tested but seems the correct way to do it. Would be nice if somebody with Admin plugin installed could verify it